# Terraform deployment will not connect EC2 to elastic container service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to set up a Terraform script to deploy an elastic container service running on an EC2 instance. Unfortunately, the [example script on the Hashicorp repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/tree/main/examples/ecs-alb) doesn't work as intended. It launches all services successfully, but the EC2 instance is not connected to the service that is built, and therefore can't run the example container. This is verified on the AWS console ECS > Infrastructure > Container instances. Nothing shown.

No reply to a GitHub issue that has been opened.

Comment: Are there any logs, errors?

Comment: No logs or errors. The ECS service just isn't connected

Comment: What does "service is not connected mean"? Not accessible through the load balancer?